# How to remove given list of documents from collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, document, mongodb-query

how to Remove given list of documents from mongodb collection? eg:

i want to remove list of students which name containing empty value like.

```
var list=db.Student.find({'Name': {$eq: ''}})

db.Student.update($pull:{list})
```

but its is not working. is there any other best solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Student.remove({'Name':''})
```

Check [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the documents with the given condition by passing a query document. Try this;

```
db.Student.remove( { Name : "" } )
```

You can refer this link for further clarifications.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/